# how to add sub query in yii when subquery return array

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I an working on an API, in which I have 2 tables 1 for library and 2nd for issued books. We can issue 5 books to any user. I am working on an API in which I need to check if any user already assigned a book then he same book will not issue to him. I used a sub query for it. but  it returns an array. So I can't get the data according my need. I need that if We issue 3 book to him than the books will show in other color. my code is:

```
$data1=(new \yii\db\Query())->select('book_id')->distinct()->from('issuedBooks')
->where('user_id=:user_id', [':user_id'=>310])->all();
$workout= (new \yii\db\Query())->select('*')->from('library')
    ->leftJoin(['issuedBooks'=>$data1],'issuedBooks.book_id=library.book_id')
    ->all();
```

$data1 return an array so my second query not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I know nothing of [Yii Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder). But I do know SQL. And usually if you want to pass parameterized queries from an array you would list out the items of array with `OR` or `IN()` using the `WHERE` clause not `JOIN`.

Using above link, consider removing the joins and using a where clause in second query, passing the array, `$data1` as a parameter:

```
->where(array('in', 'book_id', $data1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to apply left join here. You can pass sub query in where condition.

```
$data1=(new \yii\db\Query())->select('book_id')->distinct()->from('issuedBooks')
->where('user_id=:user_id', [':user_id'=>310])->all();
```

Here you will get id of books assigned to user. And use where-not-in condition to get non-assigned books.

```
$workout= (new \yii\db\Query())->select('*')->from('library')
            ->where(['not in', 'id', $data1])->all();
```

If you need left join than use like this

```
->leftJoin('issuedBooks', 'issuedBooks.book_id=library.id');
```